# In BPMN how to pack existing lanes into new pool without messing the whole diagram?

Tags: pool, enterprise-architect, bpmn

I've created a BPMN diagram with Enterprise Architect 14. It contains two separate lanes. Now I noticed that I have to pack the into pool to project collaboration with other one.

I added new pool "Cloud" and want to put both lanes into it. Unfortunately drag and drop makes a terrible mess. How to wrap my lanes into pool without necessity of reformatting of whole diagram?

[image: Diagram link][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWtOF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make `Cloud` large enough to take the lanes. I just tried that with no issue.

Comment: I thought about something like right-click "add to pool" but making it large enough work as well. Thanks!

Comment: You need to get used to "Sparxian thinking" when dealing with EA. We call that EAUI  - EA Unique Interface :-/